# Can i randomize parameters with Perl

Tags: perl, parameters

is there a way with Perl to randomize all parameters for example :

http://s.example.com/x?list=hahaha&a=&b=&c=&1

so all parameters with &a=&b=&c=&1 etc.etc.etc.

this is the output i expect?

```
for (1..10){

#random this http://s.example.com/x?list=hahaha&a=&b=&c=&1
#to be like this


print "\n";
#http://s.example.com/x?list=hahaha&b=&a=&c=&1
#http://s.example.com/x?list=hahaha&c=&a=&b=&1
##http://s.example.com/x?list=hahaha&1=&b=&1=&c

}
```

So could anyone help with this??

Thnx allready

Comment: Can you elaborate a little further??

Comment: Probably, but you'll have to go into a lot more detail if you want us to help you do it.  Right now, it's not quite clear what you're trying to accomplish.  I can print out random URL parameters on a link, but it's hard to see the use of that.

Comment: im tryin to get different requests so thats why i want randomize outcom

Comment: wait-wait, i take a power of Astral Wizard and use telepathy!

Comment: for every session i try to accompolished different
requests, is this more clearer so i can have some help with it

Answer (score 1):

You provided not that much information, but here's a (very simple) approach that should get you started.

### Code

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';
use URI;
use URI::QueryParam;

# prepare
my @all  = map {chr $_} 32 .. 126;
my @word = grep /\w/ => @all;

# randomization helpers
sub rand_number      { 1 + rand 10 }
sub rand_param_name  { join '' => map {$word[rand @word]} 1 .. rand_number }
sub rand_param_value { join '' => map {$all[rand @all]}   1 .. rand_number }

# create three uris with randomized parameters
for (1 .. 3) {

    # prepare
    my $uri = URI->new('http://s.example.com/x');

    # add randomized parameters
    $uri->query_param(rand_param_name() => rand_param_value)
        for 1 .. rand_number;

    # done
    say $uri;
}
```

### Output

```
http://s.example.com/x?TC10=MX3+B_i!
http://s.example.com/x?BaXgf=%26%7BY%5Dxt%25o&l0f=HM%5Cd%24JB%3E)&lDQ7a94=Xh%3AB3N1jK_&dzGNz3=Y8NX4o9%5BS&YnCMxDdTew=J%5B%7B~b%23&Mr8UpMhPo=H&8_nAwh8ZHe=9%5DRY%40V&EgheAy='Uk&gmqTwKW=7PyitIn&3=V%5EKApdS%2C
http://s.example.com/x?dBA7WswJ5=GX-x&yKHeb=1y1sq%3EjPt&7G=7oa%24XF%7C)jQ&FjVo5IpF=%3BZ%5C&JB7OLer=%7C55&bYo64Fiy=L%23%40&ZhSohJVZ=-W+Rp5c+%5DD&aP=zJP%7Bu&pE5URXCWq=PHZJ%60%3D97L&6Xw7Da7=.Drb
```

Comment: thnx will take a look at it ;)

Comment: That code is to `get Started!!`.. Just Joking..

Comment: You know, there is **much** more to do to randomize *all* parameters. ;) -- BTW, @user1291148, welcome to SO. The [way to say thank you](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask) here is to accept/upvote answers. I'm pretty sure my answer (which is not to take completely serious) is just a start for you, so maybe you want to show us the code you *really* needed later.

Comment: Is there also a way to send an email to an user?? so that makes communication a lil bit easier ;)

Comment: I think what happens on SO should stay on SO. ;)

Comment: haha yes i mean here on so there's no message system right??

Comment: @user1291148 SO is a q&a platform, not a social media network. If someone already was involved in the comments of a post you can alert that person by puttin `@user` in your comment. They'll get a message telling them about the comment, just like you did. But that's about it.